# AnsiString header file

Tags: c++builder, vcl, ansistring

I am migrating from an old version of Borland C++ to the newest.  In my code I had used String (AnsiString). In the new compiler it does not recognize String or AnsiString as a valid type, so I put in vcl.h in the file where I use String.  Now I get 103 errors, all saying "reference to byte is ambiguous" (various system .h files). Is vcl.h not the header for AnsiString?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The actual header file that defines `AnsiString` is `dstring.h`, and always has been (the header file that defines `UnicodeString` is `ustring.h`).  The `System::String` alias is defined in `sysmac.h`.

`vcl.h` includes these headers for you. If you are getting errors, either you did not create a VCL project properly to begin with, or your project is misconfigured.

Comment: I have a few headers where I have a class that includes AnsiString. I do have VCL.H in other places and have had no problem. Without vcl.h in this header I get unknown type errors of my AnsiString stuff. If I include vcl.h, those errors go way and I get >100 errors of the same "ambigious definition of byte". Project was set up as a vcl app. Head scratcher...

Comment: @FWE1 then please edit your question to provide a [mcve] with a sampling of the actual errors.